# C program wont arrange digits in ascending order

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I am a beginner in programming, and I am trying to create a program that will either rearrange a string of characters in alphabetical order or an array of digits in ascending order using the bubble sort to test my knowledge and understanding. 
I used the function scanf() for this as well as two different function for either the alphabet or the strings. While the alphabet one works as intended the digits one simply wont rearrange the digits in ascending order and I do not know why.

Here is the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAILLE 26
#define LENGHT 6

void croissant(char alphabet[]);
void ascend(int numero[]);

int main()
{
    int x, r;
    int numero[] = { 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1 };
    char alphabet[] = "azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn";

    printf("Pour remettre l'alphabet dans l'ordre, tapez 1 : \n\n%s\n\n\n", 
alphabet);
    printf("Pour remettre cette suite de chiffre dans l'ordre, tapez 2 : 
\n\n");
    for(x=0; x<LENGHT; x++)
    {
    printf("%d\t", numero[x]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    scanf("%d", &r);
    if(r == 1)
    {
        croissant(alphabet);
        printf("Voila : %s", alphabet);
    }
    else if(r == 2)
    {
        printf("Voila ! : ");
        ascend(numero);
        for(x=0; x<LENGHT; x++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", numero[x]);
        }
    }
    else
        puts("Je regrette, je n'ai pas compris.");


    return 0;
}

void croissant(char alphabet[])
{
    int externe, interne, temp;

    for(externe=0; externe<TAILLE-1; externe++)
    {
        for(interne=externe+1; interne<TAILLE; interne++)
        {
            if(alphabet[externe] > alphabet[interne])
            {
                temp = alphabet[externe];
                alphabet[externe] = alphabet[interne];
                alphabet[interne] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void ascend(int numero[])
{
    int temp, externe, interne;

    for(externe=0; externe<LENGHT-1; externe++);
    {
        for(interne=externe+1; interne<LENGHT; interne++)
        {
            if(numero[externe] > numero[interne])
            {
                temp = numero[externe];
                numero[externe] = numero[interne];
                numero[interne] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I apologies for my shaky english and thank you for your time.

Comment: Simple typo - you've got a semicolon at the end of the outer `for` loop - `for(externe=0; externe<LENGHT-1; externe++);`

Comment: Bubble sort compares adjacent pairs, but `externe` and `numero` are not always adjacent.

Comment: Don 't edit to add "SOLVED". Make sure that there is a good answer (make it yourself if necessary) and then accept it.

Comment: Shouldn't even need an answer since it's a simple typo - it can be just closed

Comment: @ChrisTurner Without intending to actually contradict you, I find that sometimes what looks like a typo to an  experienced programmer can be a misunderstanding of " the usual syntax" by a beginner, which merits an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you have an ; there :

```
for(externe=0; externe<LENGHT-1; externe++); // remove the ; and it will work
{
    for(interne=externe+1; interne<LENGHT; interne++)
    {
        if(numero[externe] > numero[interne])
        {
            temp = numero[externe];
            numero[externe] = numero[interne];
            numero[interne] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to add an explanation to your code-only answer? Why does removing the semicolon help?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(externe=0; externe<LENGHT-1; externe++); // I needed to remove the semicolon.
```

It was indeed a typo on my part. The added semicolon a the end of the instruction was preventing the instruction from having the desired effect. A lone semicolon in the C language is an instruction in itself, even if empty. As such, the IDE (Integrated Developpment Environment) was simply separating my instruction from the rest of the block. Preventing the digits from being arranged in ascending order.